# Send image from android to android via sockets

Tags: android, sockets

i'm new to android and I've been stuck with this for a week now, i did Google a lot
lot and try different things but nothing seem to work for me. I do get something on the client side but i can't open it. here is the **server side :**

```
public class MyServer {
Thread m_objThread;
ServerSocket m_server;
String m_strMessage;
DataDisplay m_dataDisplay;
Object m_connected;

public MyServer() {

}

public void setEventListener(DataDisplay dataDisplay) {
    m_dataDisplay = dataDisplay;
}

public void startListening() {
    m_objThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            try {

                m_server = new ServerSocket(2001);
                Socket socket = m_server.accept();

                File file = new File("/mnt/extSdCard/pic02.png");
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);


                ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                //send an object with data first here
                objectOutputStream.flush();

                byte[] b = new byte[socket.getSendBufferSize()];
                int read = 0;
                while ((read = fis.read(b)) != -1) {
                   objectOutputStream.write(b, 0, read);

                }

                objectOutputStream.close();
                fis.close();
                socket.close();

                m_server.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
    });

    m_objThread.start();

}
```

}

**The client side :**

```
public class ClientActivity extends Activity {
TextView serverMessage;
Thread m_objThreadClient;
Socket socket;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    serverMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
}

public void Start(View view) {
    m_objThreadClient = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 2001);

                InputStream reader = socket.getInputStream();
                ;
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(
                        "/mnt/extSdCard/in04.png");

                byte[] b = new byte[socket.getReceiveBufferSize()];
                int read = 0;
                while ((read = reader.read(b)) != -1) {
                    fos.write(b, 0, read);
                    fos.flush();
                    // / b = new byte[socket.getReceiveBufferSize()];
                }

                fos.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });

    m_objThreadClient.start();

}
```

}

Comment: I have seen this working with NFC, sockets are not the way to go I believe.

Comment: Don't use an `ObjectOutputStream`. Just use the `socket.getOutputStream()` to write the data to.

Comment: @BorisStrandjev Of course you can use socket for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're writing with an ObjectOutputStream but you're not reading with an ObjectInputStream. This does not work. You don't need object streams for this. Just use the streams provided by the socket.

NB Don't flush inside the loop. You don't need to keep reallocating the buffer either.